# Operations with Circulant Matrix using GAP

Tags: gap, algebraic-combinatorics, circulant-matrices

I am newbie using GAP software.

I need to know how to use GAP software for algebraic computations with circulant matrix.

Some examples would suffice.

Just for clarity
Circulant Matrix: In linear algebra, a **circulant matrix** is a square matrix in which all row vectors are composed of the same elements and each row vector is rotated one element to the right relative to the preceding row vector. It is a particular kind of **Toeplitz matrix**.

I want to find **inverse** of a circulant matrix when only first row is **even**.

Comment: ``Use'' is a too vage word.What kind of calculations do you want to do? Addition? Create groups? Also it would help to give an example of such matrices or to remind us of the definition.

Comment: Added more information for clarity.

Comment: `Inverse(M)` or `M^-1` will calculate a matrix inverse

Answer (score 0):

We can use GUAVA library to use circulant matrix. An example is given below

```
gap> LoadPackage( "guava" );
gap> k:=3; L:=[1,2,3,4];;
gap> M:=CirculantMatrix(k,L);;
gap> Display(M);
```

You can refer GUAVA library for further operations.